# Form database query from input

Tags: c, database, informix

In my C program I am receiving input which is of the form

```
     "name,age,salary|Richard,35,10000"
```

Now I want to frame insert and update queries from this input.

I am using `strtok_r` and `strtok` for this purpose.

But my problem is that while inserting or updating, I have to use double quotes around varchar data type like "Richard".

The input does not have a fixed pattern and it can be in any sequence.

- Do I have to check for the data type of each and every column every time?
- Is there a better approach?

The database I am using is Informix.  I am using ESQL/C, which is old C with embedded SQL extension.

Comment: You will need to do some clarification — quite a lot of it. You're using C, but are you using ODBC or ESQL/C for the database manipulation (or something else, but those are the two main possibilities). Does the input include the double quotes you show?  It looks like you have a list of column names separated by commas, followed by a pipe, followed by a bunch of column values, also separated by commas — is that correct? What happens if one of the column values contains a comma? How do you know which table this is going in? Or database, come to that? You say 'insert or update' — please explain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler....I am using ESQL/C. The input does not contain double quotes and yes first I have column names, then pipe, and the corresponding column values. Please ignore comma elsewhere. The table and database where I have to insert or update is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is via host variables, which means you won't need quotes around values.  Informix is pretty good about converting strings to other types; the only type you'll run into any trouble will be with blobs — BYTE, TEXT, BLOB, CLOB.

This code has only been compiled; it has not been executed.  The various `return` statements are error returns except for the last.  We can debate whether returning without freeing the prepared statement is correct; it is easily arguable that it isn't.  There should almost certainly be several routines built out of this monster.

```
#include "sqlca.h"
#include "sqlda.h"
#include "sqltypes.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int insert_record(char *line, const char *tabname);

int insert_record(char *line, const char *tabname)
{
    /* Analyze line */
    char *pipe = strchr(line, '|');
    char *comma = line;
    int c_count = 0;
    int v_count = 0;
    while ((comma = strchr(comma, ',')) != 0 && comma < pipe)
        c_count++;
    comma = pipe;
    while ((comma = strchr(comma, ',')) != 0)
        v_count++;
    if (v_count != c_count)
        return(-1);
    char *names[c_count];
    char *value[c_count];
    char *np = line;
    char *vp = pipe+1;
    for (int i = 0; i < c_count; i++)
    {
        names[i] = np;
        value[i] = vp;
        char *sep = strchr(np, ',');
        assert(sep != 0);
        if (sep > pipe)
            sep = pipe;
        *sep = '\0';
        np = sep + 1;
        sep = strchr(vp, ',');
        if (sep != 0)
        {
            *sep = '\0';
            vp = sep + 1;
        }
    }

    /* Create SQL statement with placeholders */
    /* names[i] contains column name for entry i; value[i] contains the value */
    $ char buffer[4096];
    char *sql = buffer;
    int len = sizeof(buffer) - 1;
    int num = snprintf(sql, len, "insert into %s", tabname);
    if (num <= 0 || num >= len)
        return(-2);
    if (num <= 0 || num >= len)
        return(-2);
    sql += num;
    len -= num;
    pad = "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < c_count; i++)
    {
        num = snprintf(sql, len, "%s%s", pad, "?");
        if (num <= 0 || num >= len)
            return(-2);
        sql += num;
        len -= num;
    }
    num = snprintf(sql, len, ")");
    if (num <= 0 || num >= len)
        return(-2);

    $ PREPARE p_insert FROM :buffer;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
        return(sqlca.sqlcode);

    /* Create sqlda to describe strings */
    ifx_sqlda_t data;
    ifx_sqlvar_t columns[c_count];
    $ struct sqlda *udesc = &data;
    data.sqld = c_count;
    data.sqlvar = columns;
    data.desc_name[0] = '\0';
    data.desc_occ = 0;
    data.reserved = 0;
    data.desc_next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c_count; i++)
    {
        columns[i].sqltype       = SQLVCHAR;
        columns[i].sqllen        = strlen(value[i]);
        columns[i].sqldata       = value[i];
        columns[i].sqlind        = 0;
        columns[i].sqlname       = names[i];
        columns[i].sqlformat     = 0;
        columns[i].sqlitype      = 0;
        columns[i].sqlilen       = 0;
        columns[i].sqlidata      = 0;
        columns[i].sqlxid        = 0;
        columns[i].sqltypename   = 0;
        columns[i].sqltypelen    = 0;
        columns[i].sqlownerlen   = 0;
        columns[i].sqlsourcetype = 0;
        columns[i].sqlownername  = 0;
        columns[i].sqlsourceid   = 0;
        columns[i].sqlilongdata  = 0;
        columns[i].sqlflags      = 0;
        columns[i].sqlreserved   = 0;
    }

    /* Execute the SQL and clean up */
    $ EXECUTE p_insert USING DESCRIPTOR udesc;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
        return(sqlca.sqlcode);
    $ FREE p_insert;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
        return(sqlca.sqlcode);
    return(0);
}
```